# How to write a subquery using a sub - request with IN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a migration table with attributes (name, departure year). I want to write a query giving the names of all storks that migrated in both 2001 and 2003 (using a sub-request with IN), N.B: Not allowed to use a clause such as WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT, unless it is necessary/mandatory

```
SELECT migration.NAME 
FROM migration 
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR = 2001 
IN(SELECT migration.NAME 
FROM migration 
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR = 2001)
```

This query gives me zero result

I expect the output of four names, but actually i have zero.
But when i rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT migration.NAME
FROM migration
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR IN (
SELECT migration.DEPARTUREYEAR
FROM migration
WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR IN (2001,2003))
GROUP BY migration.NAME
HAVING COUNT (*) = 2
```

The result is obtained but marked wrong.

Comment: What does 'The result is obtained but marked wrong.' mean?  The syntax in query 1 is wrong.  You cant do ```where departureyear=2001 in ...```

Comment: And why not just say: ```SELECT migration.NAME FROM migration WHERE migration.DEPARTUREYEAR in (2001,2003);```

Comment: The first query won't even run in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Your first query has the years wrong.  But more importantly, it is missing the comparison before the `IN`.  So try this:

```
SELECT m.NAME 
FROM migration m
WHERE m.DEPARTUREYEAR = 2001 AND
      m.NAME IN (SELECT m2.NAME
                 FROM migration m2
                 WHERE m2.DEPARTUREYEAR = 2003
                );
```

I am guessing that you are using MySQL.  The first version is interpreted as:

```
WHERE (migration.DEPARTUREYEAR = 2001) IN
          (SELECT m2.NAME 
           FROM migration m2
           WHERE m2.DEPARTUREYEAR = 2001
          )
```

The part before the `IN` is a boolean, which evaluates to 0 or 1.  This probably doesn't match any `NAME` values.